# Workspace integrity : The file could't be opened Xcode 5

Tags: cordova, workspace, xcode5.1

I'm developing an application in PhoneGap using Xcode 5. I created project as per steps given in PhoneGap documentation. The app worked well in last run. But as of now it's showing an **Workspace Integrity Error : The file cannot be opened.** 
This error comes-up in case of Xcode 5 and not in Xcode 4. Any idea how to deal with this issue?

[image: Error]

[image: Error description]

Comment: Did you find a solution to it? I am having the same error and can't find any.

Comment: @KutayDemireren : Nope

Answer (score 0):

Go to your xcode project file in finder, right click and select show package contents. Inside that you have this file called project.pbxproj. Open that with the text editor and see if there are many conflict texts in it like git merge conflict text ( <<<<>> ) . Xcode cannot parse this and so edit the file and save...then re open xcode.