# XCode Workspace Integrity Error

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I was commiting and pushing to git. While doing that, I got error "Workspace Integrity". I thought, that error is because I have some unmerged files, then I found out I really had unmerged files. So, finally I merged, fixed and could push to Visual Studio Online, which is my host. Then after that I tried again, but the error was the same. So, I gave it try to downloading from Visual Studio and open that downloaded project. I thought, it will not give me error. Unfortunately, as you may assume too, that didn't work.

I have to fix it, but I don't have any idea what it is. There is no such a solution for that error, which is really strange. It is the same error that was asked on stackoverflow in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932674/can-not-load-project-workspace-integrity-error-in-x-code-5-1-1) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385271/workspace-integrity-the-file-couldt-be-opened-xcode-5) before; both don't have solution.

I really need all of you extremely, that error is a bit scary.

Waiting for your guidance.

Comment: I have bad news: You have to open the `.pbxproj` file and correct the merge error yourself. It's hard to find but all the times it happened to me there were some closing braces missing. If you have an older version which works, use that. Or find someone who has done that before. Good luck.

Comment: Quick question, after I found the errors, do I have to  follow few other steps or it will open directly ? Because I think I just finished fixing the errors, but still...

Comment: What you can do is delete the PodFile.lock and Pods folder and reinstall using terminal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this similar issue and it turned out to be a merge conflict that had snuck into our git repo:

[image]

I found it by searching in my project for `<<<<< HEAD` which revealed a merge error waiting to be resolved in `project.pbxproj`

Hopefully that helps other people who end up on this stack overflow post.

Comment: actually it helped. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped. I had to open project.pbxproj in a text editor to find the issue

Answer (score 4):

What I usually do is open the file in version editor and see what has changed. 
[Version editor option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqems.png)

Answer (score 1):

Usually it happens when XCode mess up with your reference files.

Try to do a find (not on XCode, Atom you can inspect better) for "`lastKnownFileType`" and look if the references for this one are correct.

I've changed the place of few modules in the workspace, and it moved, it compiles, but cannot index due to "XCode Workspace Integrity Error
".

I've fixed by inspecting all path references and they all was related to wrong path in `lastKnownFileType`